# Write a Function 'or' without '||'

Tags: javascript, function, boolean, operator-keyword

Write a function 'or' without ||
Given 2 boolean expressions, "or" returns true or false, corresponding to the || operator.
*Should use ! and &&

```
function or(expression1, expression2) {
  return !expression1 && expression1 && !expression2 && expression1
}
```

I've tried that but at the same time I'm confused on what the question is exactly asking

Expected Output:

```
var output = or(true, false);
console.log(output); // --> true;
```

Comment: *I've tried that but at the same time I'm confused on what the question is exactly asking* - Aha! Found the homework question.

Comment: Can you provide example inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it"_ - [help]

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) you can find a hint!

Comment: Presumably before giving you this homework, your teacher introduced you to the idea that any boolean logic operand can be implemented using only NANDs. Look back at those notes, and apply what you know.

Answer (score 4):

Some basic consideration, with [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
!(a && b) = !a || !b 
!(a || b) = !a && !b
```

```js
function or(a, b) {
    return !(!a && !b);
}

console.log(or(false, false)); // false
console.log(or(false, true));  // true
console.log(or(true, false));  // true
console.log(or(true, true));   // true
```

Answer (score 2):

here is the working solution

```js
function or(a, b){
if(!a && !b) 
 return false
return true;
}

console.log(or(true, true));
console.log(or(true, false));
console.log(or(false, true));
console.log(or(false, false));
```

hope this helps!!

Comment: An explanation would help, as just providing the answer won't help the OP learn. (This is a homework question after all)

Answer (score 0):

The concept they are asking you to show is something called a NAND or Not AND

NAND is the most common type of of logic operator in electronics and can be used to represent all other logic.

You can find a representation of what you should be modeling here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic#OR

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation:

```
   return !a && b && !a && b
```

For `true` and `false` this evaluates to:

```
   return !true && true && !false && false;
```

i.e.

```
   return false && true && true && false;
```

Because of *lazy evaluation*, it doesn't even evaluate anything after the first `false &&` because `false && x` is false regardless of the value of `x`. For any input, one of the terms is `false`, so it will always return false.

It may help if you break it into smaller parts:

```
 boolean bothFalse = !a && !b
 boolean notBothFalse = !bothFalse;
 return notBothFalse;
```

But using brackets `()` you can express this in a single line. I'll leave this as an exercise for you.